# Excel file upload is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following method to upload excel to my ASP.NET MVC application. This is working fine in mozilla and chrome but in IE.

```
        public ActionResult FileUploadForBookCreation(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            bool errorvalue = false;
            bool duplicateInFile = false;
            var lstProductDetails = new List<ProductDetailsForBooksExcel>();
            var objProductDetailsvalidation = new ProductDetailsvalidation();
            var objproductViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
            var lstProductDetailsvalidation = new List<ProductDetailsvalidation>();
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string validation;
            if (extension.Equals(".xls") || extension.Equals(".xlsx"))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), fileName);

                file.SaveAs(path);
                ValidateBookCreationfile(path, false, objProductDetailsvalidation, lstProductDetails, objproductViewModel, lstProductDetailsvalidation);

                if (lstProductDetailsvalidation.Any())
                {

                    return Json(lstProductDetailsvalidation);
                }
                return Json(lstProductDetails);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Error");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }
    }
```

Anybody have any idea why its happening only in IE11? :(

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Also show us your HTML code. Are you using AJAX/JQuery to upload the file?

Comment: @ramiramilu its not working means its not accepting any files. Yes i am using Ajax jquery